# Not Able to Change Volume with Cron (tried Python)

Tags: python-3, cron, audio-playback, raspberry-pi-desktop

Alright, I've been trying this for several days and I'm just dying here...

I am putting together a kiosk that should play video. I'm using a NUC with Raspberry Pi Desktop. Everything works but automating the audio with Cron. I work in a school and blasting sound during the day would kind of suck, so I want it to change based on the time of the day.

When run from terminal the following code works:

```
/usr/bin/amixer set Master 16384
```

and

```
amixer sset 'Master' 16384
```

So, I put it into Cron.

```
15 09 * * * /usr/bin/amixer set Master 16384
```

or

```
43 09 * * * amixer sset 'Master' 16384
```

Nothing. Fine. So I make a really simple python script to run.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from subprocess import call
call(["/usr/bin/amixer", "set", "Master", "65536"])
```

I make it executable:

```
chmod +x /etc/python/sound100.py
```

Then I call it from the terminal with both:

```
/etc/python/sound100.py
```

and

```
/usr/bin/python3 /etc/python/sound100.py
```

Again, it works. Yay. Into Cron it goes. Neither:

```
11 10 * * * python3 /etc/python/sound100.py
```

nor

```
11 10 * * * /usr/bin/python3 /etc/python/sound100.py
```

Not even

```
11 10 * * * /etc/python/sound100.py
```

Nothing works.

So begins the actual troubleshooting. I check the syslog. Everything runs, but I learn that when I run it as a `sudo` command it doesn't work. It says that the maximum volume is 83 when run as a sudoer. So that means I can't run it as from `sudo crontab -e`, but I start running it from the user's cron.

Still freaking nothing. So, alright, fine, I'll try running it as a sudoer but with the user beforehand. Nothing again.

I am exhausted and this isn't even my full-time job. I'm a librarian. I'm just technically inclined and had done this before with regular raspberry pi 4s. Just no volume because they weren't powerful enough.

Please help me. I just want to adjust the volume automatically without logging into a ssh for every NUC we're putting up.

Comment: This looks like a simple programming Question - nothing to do with Pi.     Raspberry Pi Desktop - is a Linux OS with the Raspbian Look&Feel. **Why** would you put your undocumented program in a system directory?

Comment: Maybe try systemd and target something late in the boot process?